# How to do more than one verify_nonce in one function?

Tags: validation

I use a function to inset post at front_end. There are 3 different types of actions may trigger this function. So, in this function, should I write 3 verify_nonce?

Answer (score 1):

Nonce generated is product of:

- user ID
- time
- `$action` argument

The action is important part and needs to precisely describe what kind of event you are verifying. So if your actions are *create something* and *delete something*, your nonces should be generated for example like `my_prefix_create` and `my_prefix_delete` and verified accordingly.